# XNA Hold screen to move object

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

im working with windows phone game using xna... and looking a way to make my object to move with holding some rectangle that i made as a button on screen....

i already tried this but it just read tap gesture only

```
          foreach (GestureSample gestureSample in input.Gestures)
                {
                    switch (gestureSample.GestureType)
                    {
                      case GestureType.Hold:
                      case GestureType.Tap:
                      Point tapLocation = new Point((int)gestureSample.Position.X, (int)gestureSample.Position.Y);
                      if (rightRectangle.Contains(tapLocation))
                                {
                                        rightTouched = true;
                                        player.Catapult.CurrentState = CatapultState.MoveRight;
                                        playerPositionUpdate.X += 20;
                                        player.catapultPosition.X += 20;
                                        player.Catapult.catapultPosition.X += 20;
                                        player.Catapult.projectilePositionUpdate.X += 20;
                                        if (player.Catapult.catapultPosition.X == player.Catapult.catapultPosition.X + 20)
                                            rightTouched = false;
                                        CenterOnPosition(player.Catapult.Position - catapultCenterOffset);
                                    }
                       break;
                      }
                 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above you shouldn't use `GestureSample` for that purpose, because using dragcomplete and freedrag a bit tricky. Instead you should code your own gestures using `TouchPanel.GetState()`

```
TouchCollection touchCollection = TouchPanel.GetState();
        if (touchCollection.Count == 1)
        {
            var touch = touchCollection[0]; 
            switch (touch.State)
            {
                case TouchLocationState.Pressed:
                    if (rectangle.Contains((int) touch.Position.X, (int)  touch.Position.Y))
                    {
                        isMoving = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case TouchLocationState.Moved:
                    if (isMoving)
                    {
                        TouchLocation prevLocation;
                        touch.TryGetPreviousLocation(out prevLocation);
                        if (prevLocation.Position != touch.Position)
                        {
                            Vector2 delta = touch.Position - prevLocation.Position;
                            //offset your rectangle on delta
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case TouchLocationState.Released:
                    isMoving = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if (touchCollection.Count == 2)
        {
            var touchOne = touchCollection[0];
            var touchTwo = touchCollection[1];
            //pinch logic here
        }
```

I guess you understand the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Gestures are discrete events. You want to poll the state of the touch panel every frame. Use `TouchPanel.GetState()` for that.

See [Working with Touch Input (Windows Phone)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434208.aspx) for information.

Comment: hmmm it's not working i tried to using like the link in the code.. hmm is it right if i use this line of code to get the position of my touch? "Point touchPoint = new Point((int)tl.Position.X,(int)tl.Position.Y);" and using "if(rightRectangle.Contains(touchPoint))"? oh and i forgot to mention, i also have freedrag,dragcomplete,flick,pinch gesture in my code.... i think it have something to do... because when i tried to hold in screen and moving my finger it looks like freedrag gesture triggered(my camera following my finger)

Comment: Then just disable gesture recognition for now and see if it has something to do with it.